# AR App: Taking pattern and turning it into image plane

Tags: 3d

I'm doing Augmented Reality research and am using OpenCV. I have the find checkerboard working and am wanting to put some 3D graphics on the checkerboard.

In OpenCV the findCheckerboard function will find the corners of the blocks of your checkerboard. What I have done so far is taken the four outermost corners and placed an image on the checkerboard doing an affine transformation.

I'm wanting to expand this to a 3D model. I'm thinking that once you get the four corners you'll somehow move the camera to make it look like the 3D image is on top of the checkboard. I'm I thinking correctly about this?

If so, how on earth do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [osgART](http://www.osgart.org/wiki/Main_Page) for this since it contains [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) which would help with attaching 3D models to your tag(s). Unless you really need to use OpenCV, doing all the detection, orientation, and positioning with OpenCV would be a bit more work than just using an AR library.

If osgART isn't for you, look into [ARToolKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARToolKit) or its derivatives([ARToolKitPlus](https://launchpad.net/artoolkitplus)) for something that better suits your needs.